# Astyle - how to format condition without braces to 1TBS

Tags: c++, c, parsing, astyle

I have a program which uses Astyle to format the code into 1TBS. So, if I have a code like this

```
if(condition)
    func(a, b);
```

it changes to this

```
if(condition) {
    func(a, b);
}
```

---

**The problem** is, when parameters in the called function are broken into multiple lines, like this:

```
if(condition)
    func(a, 
         b);
```

Then Astyle is not able to add braces even if I try to force him with `--add-brackets`. Is it possible to do it some other way?

My command now looks like this:

```
astyle --style=1tbs --add-brackets  test.c
```

Comment: Maybe clang-format can do this?

Comment: @EOF maybe it can, but I'd prefer to stick with Astyle, if possible. Our program is quite large already even without other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem a bit convoluted but if you have a lot of sources
and adding braces is an operation that you just need once,
the following scheme might work.

You can stick with astyle but you need [uncrustify](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify) temporarily
as well as a script I wrote called [whatstyle](https://github.com/mikr/whatstyle).

In the following steps replace `test1.c` with your sources and keep a backup
of your sources as they will be modified.

## Teach astyle the current style of your sources

```
whatstyle.py -f astyle --mode resilient --output astylerc test1.c
```

## Teach uncrustify the current style of your sources

```
whatstyle.py -f uncrustify --output uncrustify.cfg test1.c
```

## Tell uncrustify to always add braces to ifs

```
( egrep -v mod_full_brace_if < uncrustify.cfg ; echo "mod_full_brace_if = force" ) \
  > uncrustify_addbrace.cfg
```

## Reformat your sources with as little style changes as possible with uncrustify

```
uncrustify --replace -c uncrustify_addbrace.cfg test1.c
```

## The braces have been added now retransform into the original style with astyle.

```
ARTISTIC_STYLE_OPTIONS=astylerc astyle test1.c
```

Now your sources should look almost the same as before except for the added braces
although there might be more changes by the back-and-forth style transformation.